# What does the operator |= mean in Java?

Tags: java, operators, calculator

I am confused about the meaning of the `|=` operator.

At first, I thought `checker|=(1<<val)` means `checker= checker+checker|(1<<val)`. I have debugged the code, and the result tells me `checker|=(1<<val)` is different than `checker= checker+checker|(1<<val)`.

How does the `|=` operator work?

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str){
   int checker = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<str.length();++i){
       int val = str.charAt(i)-'a';
       if((checker &(1<<val))>0) return false;
       checker |=(1<<val);  // what does it mean ?
      // checker= checker +checker|(1<<val);
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it means

```
checker = checker|(1<<val)
```

it will effectively set bit number [val] to be 1 - bitwise OR with a pattern thats a single 1 shifted left [val] times

Answer (score 2):

```
checker |=(1<<val);
```

is the same as

```
checker = checker|(1<<val)
```

| is the logical OR operation (bit level)

Answer (score 2):

```
a |= b;
```

is a short form of:

```
a = a | b;
```

This goes for C, C++, Java, Python, and probably a bunch more languages, all inspired to some degree by C.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `foo x= bar` means `foo = foo x bar`. Therefore `foo |= bar` is `foo = foo | bar`.